# Couchdb disk size 10x aggregrate document size

Tags: compression, couchdb

I have a couchdb with ~16,000 similar documents of about 500 bytes each. The stats for the db report (commas added):

```
"disk_size":73,134,193,"data_size":7,369,551
```

Why is the disk size 10x the data_size? I would expect, if anything, for the disk size to be smaller as I am using the default (snappy) compression and this data should be quite compressible.

I have no views on this DB, and each document has a single revision. Compaction has very little effect.

Here's the full output from hitting the DB URI:

```
{"db_name":"xxxx","doc_count":17193,"doc_del_count":2,"update_seq":17197,"purge_seq":0,"compact_running":false,"disk_size":78119025,"data_size":7871518,"instance_start_time":"1429132835572299","disk_format_version":6,"committed_update_seq":17197}
```

Comment: Are there any old revisions of documents? Have you tried compaction? https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Compaction
Can you verify the size on disk using "ls -liah"?

Comment: Updated the question: No old versions, and I tried compaction to more or less no effect. I guess I'm just curious if this is normal - does anyone have a couch DB they could check?

Comment: Have you deleted any documents from couchdb? Make a get request to your database(http://localhost:5984/db_name) and you should see a response like `{"db_name":"my_db","doc_count":21,"doc_del_count":0,"update_seq":32,"purge_seq":0,"compact_running":false,"disk_size":49256,"data_size":46513,"instance_start_time":"1431492912363200","disk_format_version":6,"committed_update_seq":32}` we are interested in the doc_del_count. couchdb "preserves" deleted documents that might increase the database size.

Comment: I have deleted a couple documents out of 16k. I've added the full output of the DB URI above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are getting correct results. couchdb stores documents in chunks of 4kb each (can't find a reference at the moment but you can test it out by storing an empty document). That is min size of a document is 4kb.

Which means that even if you store a data of 500 bytes per document couchdb is going to save it in chunks of 4kb each. So doing a rough calculation

`17193*4*1024+(2*4*1024)= 70430720`

That seems to be in the range of 78119025  still a little less but that could be due to the way files are stored on the disk.

Comment: Thanks, I think that is close to being it. It seems that it is not actually that it stores always documents in 4K chunks, but rather than each write to the append-only log that forms the basis for the DB always takes 4K as [described here](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/btree.html). Since I'm writing documents one-by-one, I pay 4K per document. That isn't an inherent limitation though - when I replicated this database to another host, the size dropped by 8x, and the disk size was now every close to the total document size. The documents were written in batches so the 4K limit is bypassed.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I was looking for it. A similar thing happens if you insert your documents in [bulk](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API#Modify_Multiple_Documents_With_a_Single_Request). So if you want to reduce the size of the database you could also batch your requests in to a single bulk insert. It will be optimized for storage.